# Can an old-cement garage floor be painted in sections?

Tags: painting, paint, garage, cement

This question is related to our other question about relocation of our hot water heater. The current plan is to put the new water heater in the garage on the cement floor, so our concern is how to prepare the area where the new water heater will reside. So, initially, we may only paint the area under the tank. There's too much stuff in the garage to paint the whole floor all at once.

So this question results from the confluence of two projects. The garage floor as it is, is abysmal, so we want to make it better. It has not been painted. The cement must be several decades old. (The house was built in 1977, but the cement floor was added later. We believe that the area was initially a carport with crushed rock.)

I am having a difficult time thinking of how I could make the question more focused--probably because I don't know anything about painting cement. Web searches mostly return hype from vendors. I sincerely appreciate the help from those who don't mind assisting a confessed novice.

Comment: "What do I need to know" isn't a question that fits well with our Q&A format. You'll need to revise to ask something more specific.

Comment: You may want to search [diy.se] for the [tag:painint] and [tag:garage] tags. I'd imagine this has been asked at least once. You should find info on prep work and coating options. Please feel free to [edit] this question to cover a specific detail that you're not sure about.

Comment: we're good at specific questions (and often ones that are hard to find answers to by Google searching). If you turn one up, let us know

Comment: @FreeMan, Thank you. That's helpful. I will continue my search. I usually don't ask questions on forums until I am frustrated with other sources. I guess I need to avoid asking dumb questions here.

Comment: @Ack, About which do you want me to let you know, a specific question or a specific answer? I suspect, though, that when I have done enough research to know what questions to ask, I shall also know the answers.

Comment: @isherwood, I will edit the question.

Comment: The cleaning really is not two hard muriatic acid is what is used in swimming pools, badly oiled surface 10% pour the water I use a broom and move the water around I do it with the door open.   The rough texture or broom finish will hold a fair amount of paint but you can smooth the surface dramatically with a good coat I have used 2 coats on a broom finish . I have also used a surface grinder what a mess but the owner a friend of mine wanted almost glass smooth, grinding and - coat he was happy, grinding was not that hard with the right grinding disk but the slurry took quite a few rinses.

Comment: Umm... that's the [tag:painting] tag, not "painint" tag... Also, it's not that your question is "dumb", but that it's fairly broad and that doesn't fit well with the way StackExchange sites work. If you can imagine a magazine article or book as the answer to your question, it's too broad (and there are books about painting). TBH, the way it reads now isn't _too_ bad. If you focus even more on "what do I need to do to prep a garage floor for painting", it's even a great fit for the answer you got!

Comment: @FreeMan, Thanks. That's helpful. I tried editing it, but am frustrated and became angry at the initial comment. It would be helpful if there were a way to know that criticism is coming from an admin. My first thought was that I had encountered a troll. So, I think I just need to give up on this one and muddle through on my own. I'm too much of a novice to compose the question properly. This is also my first experience with the StackExchange culture. Apparently, the site is about solving problems and I am not smart enough about painting cement to frame the question as a specific problem.

Comment: There are "admins" you can identify them by a diamond symbol after their name, but the site is pretty well self-policed by the populace, and there really aren't a lot of trolls - they tend to get shut down pretty darn quickly. We were all novices at one point, so don't worry - some of us were novices before the internet was full of helpful info and helpful people. Usually, you'll get some good guidance on _how_ to rework your question to bring it up to snuff, sometimes someone will edit if for you. We do prefer specific questions, and usually will help you get to one....

Comment: There's nothing wrong with going from one specific question to another to another as you learn. That's much more preferable around here than one huge, broad question. Don't take any of the comments personally (heck, you don't know the people and they don't know you, how could it have been personal?), just take them as an opportunity to learn.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't think I have any more for this thread right now. I received enough help to get started. The area where the hot water tank is going is relatively clean, so that should be a good place to start painting. The folks here are very helpful and I very much appreciate all the contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important step is cleaning the best 2 part epoxy paint can’t stick to a oily floor.
First it needs to be cleaned 100% I suggest an acid wash using muriatic acid and water, 3% to 10% for badly oil stained floors, the muriatic etches the concrete as it dose it is neutralized with the weaker solution, then a good rinse 2 or 3 times let dry and you are ready for paint.

The quality of the paint is the next most important thing. I use 2 part epoxy paint made specifically for garage floors rustolium has a good product out there I have used several times

Don’t go cheap or use 1 part epoxy paints, a friend followed my cleaning advice
But went with a 1 part epoxy that when car tires sat on it started peeling the paint up (hot tires can cause failure) I rented a shot blaster to clean this off it took 2 full days because he wanted to do it right the 2nd time.

Follow instructions I use a heavy nap roller work from the back wall to the opening.
I would recommend using the color chips or an abrasive powder as you roll the paint scattered on the surface it doesn’t take much but you will thank me if you ever spill antifreeze on your floor (it is slicker than ice with no abrasive) I recleaned my shop and added a thin 2nd coat with abrasive sprinkled it still looked awesome but I poured some antifreeze and water on the new surface and could walk on it, without the abrasive I could not stand.

Once the floor is cured 24-72 hours depending on brand it is ready for abuse and is really easy to clean oil up kitty litter to pick up the bulk then a few squirts of laundry soap or dish soap and the floor looks like new again, I use a 3’ squeegee to push water out.

Depending on how rough or The porosity Of the surface you may need more paint than the can says it will cover, I think the ones that said 300sf / can were glass smooth floors rougher plan for 250 sf if it says 300.

Those are the things I have done many times for myself and others.  hope it helps.

Comment: Ed, how about testing for moisture before applying any paint?

Comment: @Ed Beal, Thank you. This sounds like a bigger project than we thought it would be. We would definitely have much cleaning to do. We were concerned about painting over the oil. Also, the surface of the garage floor is much rougher than we want it to be. It has grooves in it like those often seen on sidewalks. That's why we want to paint it. We want to be able to sweep and mop it easily. As it is now, it is hard to sweep because it is so rough. We were also wondering about one-step versus two-step paints. Your response was particularly helpful on that point.

Comment: I do test by putting a square of plastic down for 24 hours some brands don’t require it but the rustolium did in my cases I have only had limited problemS with a garage it was a daylight basement with the garage under the upper level , we waited until summer and it was dry enough 1 garage on grade with a spring fixed drainage fans on 48 hours prior to coating. So check and if the instructions state to test a piece of plastic taped down for 24 hours Will do the test if water is dripping off the plastic additional measures need t be considered (I use a trash bag do I can re use it ). +